# "Вначале" или "в начале". Как верно?

Tags: орфография

В начале рассмотрим эту часть ответа: "сотрудники посещали..." Почему?

Comment: Контекста не хватает. Если "в начале [письма, методички, разбора]", то раздельно. Иначе слитно.

Comment: В начале (существительное, вопрос: в чем/когда) чего-то/разговора/текста/обсуждения/дня. Вначале (наречие, вопрос: строго когда). Вначале он был другим, потом нет. В начале (своей жизни) он был другим. Вначале мы говорили о нем, потом о другом. В начале (беседы) мы говорили о нем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что тут больше подходит "сначала":

> *Сначала рассмотрим эту часть ответа...*

*сначала* — в первую **очередь**
*вначале* — в первое **время**

*С начала* и *в начале* употребляются с дополнением: в начале или с начала **чего-то.** Например, *в начале / с начала лета, в начале документа есть то-то и то-то.* Кроме того, можно вставить слово "самый": *с с**а**мого начала / в с**а**мом начале.* У *вначале* есть ещё близкий синоним с тем же корнем: *поначалу.*

Comment: Возможно, отличия в следующем, но я не уверен, поскольку всё перемешивается: Сначала = вначале и далее. Сначала время шло медленно, затем ускорилось. Сначала забег не задавался.

Comment: @user190920, нет, не "и далее". Да, у "сначала" больше значений: то, что я привёл, и полный синоним "вначале". В ваших примерах как раз синоним и есть. :)

Answer (score 1):

Согласно орфографической норме русского языка оба варианта являются правильными. Выбор того или иного варианта зависит от контекста.

Мы пишем слово раздельно, если в предложении оно играет роль существительного с предлогом, руководствуясь правилом:

*“Существительное с предлогом пишется раздельно”.*

**Как понять, что перед нами существительное?**

Как правило, у выражения будет зависимое слово (например: в начале разговора, где “разговор” – это зависимое слово) и существительное употребляется в своем прямом значении.

А также, если между словом и предлогом можно вставить определение, то это без сомнений существительное с предлогом (например: в самом начале).

**Когда пишем слитно?**

Мы пишем слово слитно, если в предложении оно играет роль наречия.

Здесь мы руководствуемся следующим правилом:

*“Слитно пишутся наречия, которые образованы от существительных с пространственным и временным значением”.*

Существительное “начало” имеет временное значение, поэтому правописание подчиняется данному правилу.

**Как понять, что перед нами наречие, а не существительное с предлогом?**

В предложении наречие “вначале” не имеет определения (зависимого слова).

[Источник](https://russkiypro.ru/pravilnoe-pravopisanie-v-nachale-ili-vnachale/)